# Merge two dataframe by day to make one graph

Tags: python, pandas

So i have this two dataframe

df1 and df2

df1 :

```
Data1 Created
1     22-01-01      
4     22-01-01
3     22-01-01
```

df2 :

```
Data1 Created
1     22-01-01      
6     23-01-01
```

each have the same columns names.

And i would like to use the same column "Created" which is a date to count occurence by day and plot them in the same graph.

I've tried this :

```
ax = df1.plot()
df2.plot(ax=ax,x_compat=True,figsize=(20,10))
```

but i have this :

[image]

Edit :
df2.resample('D').sum() give me :

```
Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

I've try this also :

```
ax = df1.set_index('Created').resample('1D', how='count').plot()
df2.set_index('Created').resample('1D', how='count').plot(ax=ax,x_compat=True,figsize=(20,10))
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or?

Comment: @RafaelC here are my try

Comment: @user462794 where are you stuck? in joining the dfs? why not just concat them and groupby sum

Comment: concat them and groupby @anky_91

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': np.random.randint(0,30,size=10),'Created': pd.date_range("20180101", periods=10)})                  
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': np.random.randint(0,30,size=10),'Created': pd.date_range("20180103", periods=10)}) 
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Created', how='outer').fillna(0)
df['sum'] = df['Data1_x']+df['Data1_x']
```

df have all the data.

To plot the sum together

```
plt.plot(df['sum'], df['Created'])
```

Or two plots

```
plt.plot(df['Data1_x'], df['date'])
plt.plot(df['Data1_y'], df['date'])
```

Comment: KeyError: "['2019-02-22T22:35:06.628000000' '2019-02-22T22:37:44.546000000'\n '2019-02-23T04:53:17.925000000' ... '2019-03-23T13:18:20.682000000'\n '2019-03-23T13:21:16.902000000' '2019-03-23T13:50:51.719000000'] not in index"

Comment: @user462794 is your dataframe proper ? check the column names and datatypes of columns.

Comment: @Parfait agreed. I tried on df's with different columns and copied it here renaming the columns. missed it while copying